# How to integrate selenium with lighthouse

Tags: selenium, lighthouse

We are currently trying to integrate **selenium** with **lighthouse**.

When we try with the below command we were able to trigger the lighthouse for 1 url.

`lighthouse https://application.com/app --port=1156--collect.settings.maxWaitForFcp="45000" --emulated-form-factor=none--output=html --output-path=./GoogleHome.html`

But We want it to be integrated with the selenium so that we can run one full flow from login into the logout.

````
        options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:1156");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        // Label: Launch
        driver.get(" https://application.com/app");```

with the above code in the selenium script we are getting the below error
Note the URL provided in the script is valid and we can navigate it manually.
Note: the port number dynamically generated in the selenium is used in the command.

Error:
```config:warn IFrameElements gatherer requested, however no audit requires it. +0ms
  config:warn FormElements gatherer requested, however no audit requires it. +3ms
Runtime error encountered: The URL you have provided appears to be invalid.
LHError: INVALID_URL    at Function.run (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\runner.js:79:17)
    at lighthouse (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\index.js:52:17)
    at runLighthouse (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-cli\run.js:226:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)```

Any recommendation on what's missing?
````

Comment: Have you ever got this to work?

Comment: See the last section of this writeup https://www.automatetheplanet.com/ui-performance-analysis-webdriver-csharp/